# In C++, why is the subtraction result between iterators a long not other types?

Tags: c++

Why is the subtraction result between iterators a long not other types?

For example:

```
vector<int> data{1, 2, 3, 4};
vector<int>::iterator curr = data.begin();

cout << typeid(curr - data.begin()).name();
```

Gives:

```
l
```

Comment: You subtracted an iterator `curr` with an iterator `data.begin()`

Comment: Very strong possibility of negative numbers, so unsigned's not a viable option.

Comment: What kind of type do you expect instead?

Comment: It's actually (according to the Standard, IIRC) a `std::ptrdiff_t`. On your platform, that's defined as a `long`; on mine (64-bit MSVC), it's an `__int64` (= `long long int`).

Comment: The result doesn't have to be `long`, but it is a reasonable option. What other options are reasonable in your opinion?

Comment: Subtracting iterators works the same way as pointer arithmetik does, as an iterator is a fancy pointer. In pointer arithmetik, each pointer holds the address of the referenced data and subtracting them gives you the distance in bytes (which can be quite useful in c). Subtracting iterators yields the same result (number of bytes inbetween) which is returned as a long (I guess to ensure an address can be stored).

Comment: @AdrianMole It's not `std::ptrdiff_t` according to the standard. It's just implementation defined. But there's a high likelihood that those types correlate.

Comment: @eerorika Yes, you are technically correct: *When working with the C++ container library, the proper type for the difference between iterators is the member typedef difference_type, which is often synonymous with std::ptrdiff_t.*

Comment: @Dames `In pointer arithmetik, each pointer holds the address of the referenced data and subtracting them gives you the distance in bytes` This is incorrect except in the case where the size of the object is one byte. Subtracting pointers gives you the distance in number of objects in an array. Subtracting iterators gives you the distance in number of elements in a range.

Comment: @Dames Also, while pointers are useful iterators, iterators are only sometimes pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> In C++, why is the subtraction result between iterators a long not other types?

It is not necessarily `long`. It can be another signed integer type.

The standard library implementation that you use has chosen `long`. The type wasn't another type in your case because the standard library implementers didn't choose another type.